# How to move all subCategories (ShopWare 5.4.6)

Tags: shopware

I have subcategories (using [Shopware](https://en-community.shopware.com)) and want to move them to empty MyNewCategory.

I tried (with no success) to find the empty category by using this select:

```
SELECT c.categoryID FROM s_articles_categories AS c 
WHERE c.categoryID not in (SELECT r.parentCategoryID from s_articles_categories_ro AS r )
```

I found all category including articles by using this select [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5hQV.jpg) :

```
SELECT parentCategoryID FROM `s_articles_categories_ro` 
GROUP BY parentCategoryID
```

[image: all Categories including articles]

How could i move all subCategories to another Categorie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you move them directly in the backend? This is possible by Drag'n'Drop and even the ID of the categorie is shown in the backend. Since the backend validates these steps, this would be the safest way.

But the category-tree is stored in s_categories - the s_article_categories* tables only holds the assignment of products to those categories. You don't need to change anything in these tables. After you change the tree in s_categories you need to rebuild the category-tree in the backend (Settings > Caches/performances > Settings > Categories). This will recreate the product assignments and fix the parentIDs in s_articles_categories_ro.

Comment: Whey? Yes, moving the categories using **drag'n'drop in the backend** works for me too. I miss the checkbox there: Mark all categories. But I want to automate it. With the mouse, I seldom happen to unprudinable errors, as through a script or SQL commands. I hope that these automations will also work in the long term, making them faster, safer and easier to scale up. Incidentally, I get a deeper understanding of this Shopware.

Comment: The s_articles_categories_ro is the problem in your case. When the parent of a category changes, those changes need to be applied to the _ro table. This table is used as read only table to display the products in the correct categories in the frontend (inheritance from leaf-categories to the upper ones).